# Create a dummy variable based on two variables x1 and x2 (dummy=x1 only if at least one adjacent x2=yes)

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dummy-variable

Below is the code to generate the dataframe for demonstration:

```
d<-data.frame(x1=c(rep("no",5),rep("yes",4),rep("no",2),rep("yes",3),rep("no",2),rep("yes",3)),
              x2=c(rep("no",6),rep("yes",1),rep("no",9),rep("yes",2),rep("no",1)),
              dummy=c(rep(0,5),rep(1,4),rep(0,5),rep(0,2),rep(1,3)))
```

I have two variables x1 and x2. What I want is a dummy variable, named as 'dummy', based on both x1 and x2 indicators. Specifically, the dummy should equal 1 by capturing all x1=yes values conditional that at least one of its adjacent x2=yes. If x1=yes but its adjacent x2=no, then the dummy should be 0.

It is easy to create a dummy variable taking value of 1 when both x1 and x2 equal 'yes', using

```
d$dummy=ifelse(d$x1=="yes" & d$x2=="yes",1,0)
```

But it would not be able to capture the whole cluster of x1=yes which is what I wish to do.

The desired output I am looking for is like this:
[image]

Any idea how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `group_by` consecutive_ids, and then get 1 if `x1 == "yes"`, and any adjacent `x2 is "yes"`.

```r
library(dplyr) #1.1.0+
d %>% 
  group_by(cons = consecutive_id(x1)) %>% 
  mutate(dummy = +(x1 == "yes" & any(x2 == "yes"))) %>%
  ungroup()

   x1    x2    dummy  cons
   <chr> <chr> <int> <int>
 1 no    no        0     1
 2 no    no        0     1
 3 no    no        0     1
 4 no    no        0     1
 5 no    no        0     1
 6 yes   no        1     2
 7 yes   yes       1     2
 8 yes   no        1     2
 9 yes   no        1     2
10 no    no        0     3
11 no    no        0     3
12 yes   no        0     4
13 yes   no        0     4
14 yes   no        0     4
15 no    no        0     5
16 no    no        0     5
17 yes   yes       1     6
18 yes   yes       1     6
19 yes   no        1     6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response! This is almost there but the dummy for rows 12-14 should be 0 since none of the adjacent x2 value is "yes'. Do you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Check edit, it's a bit more complicated

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data.table::rleid()` to create groups with blocks of `x1`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

d %>% mutate(gp = rleid(x1)) %>% 
  group_by(gp) %>% 
  mutate(dummy2 = ifelse(x1 == "yes" & any(x2 == "yes") , 1, 0))

# A tibble: 19 × 5
# Groups:   gp [6]
   x1    x2    dummy    gp dummy2
   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
 1 no    no        0     1      0
 2 no    no        0     1      0
 3 no    no        0     1      0
 4 no    no        0     1      0
 5 no    no        0     1      0
 6 yes   no        1     2      1
 7 yes   yes       1     2      1
 8 yes   no        1     2      1
 9 yes   no        1     2      1
10 no    no        0     3      0
11 no    no        0     3      0
12 yes   no        0     4      0
13 yes   no        0     4      0
14 yes   no        0     4      0
15 no    no        0     5      0
16 no    no        0     5      0
17 yes   yes       1     6      1
18 yes   yes       1     6      1
19 yes   no        1     6      1
```